# Allow external users to access my DB through Linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

What do i need to configure to allow external users from different domain to access a few tables in my SQL DB?

I've created in the past a connection to external linked server by one of our clients who provided me with an IP , username and password.

I want to do the same from my side now, No sure how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To clarify: You want to grant access to your database to an external entity?

You will need to provide them the same three things:

- IP Address or Server Name if it resolves on their end (and firewall permissions)
- UserName - That has as minimal permissions as you can.
- Password

You can then either have all the external entities share the same username and password, or create new ones for each external.  If they all need the same permissions then I strongly recommend creating a database role that has them then you can just add the user to the role and be done.

**CAUTION**

How external are we talking here?  Outside your company or just outside your domain?  Because exposing your SQL server to the world is a generally bad idea.

Additionally, depending on how they write their queries and what they are doing, you could see significantly increased load on your server.  Naive use of linked servers can quickly drag performance down.  If you have a readable secondary, I recommend having them connect to that one.

Personally, if it was outside the company then I would sit the business down and make them understand how risky this could be.  Preference would be to do data dumps instead, use SSIS or PowerShell to run a query, dump the data to csv and let them ingest and process.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Fite, Thanks for getting back and i do really appreciate your recommendations about the risk of exposing our server to be used externally and the down side of using Linked server which could lead into performance issues, We decided to create a virtual machine and allow the users to connect to it and access our DB with very limited access.